# Test project with pytest in different folder

Tags: python-3.x, flask, pytest

I'm trying to add pytest to a flask app. This is the project structure.

```
root
├── myapp
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── module
│   │   ├── models.py
│   ├── pages
│   │   ├── forms.py
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   │   ├── base.html
│   │   │   ├── home.html
│   │   │   └── login.html
│   │   └── views.py
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── __pycache__
└── tests
    ├── conftest.py
    └── test_pages.py
```

The flask app is under `myapp` folder. The command `flask run` runs ok under this folder. So the app is working fine on its own.

The test folder is at the same level as `myapp`. If I run `pytest` or `py.test` I get this error.

```
conftest.py:3: in <module>
    from app import app
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

conftest.py

```
from pytest import fixture

from app import app

@fixture
def client():
    return app.app
```

I want a way to pytest to recognize `myapp` as the root of the project. Even if they are in different folders.

Comment: Create an empty `conftest.py` file in `myapp` dir.

Comment: @hoefling this will pollute the actual app with test files. Add an `__init__.py` maybe.